# Should transfer learning from the whole data set be used tuning individual model?

Tags: neural-networks, transfer-learning

I have a dataset of many timeseries and I want to develop anomaly detection with neural networks for each individual timeseries.

Are there any benefits training a generic model on the whole dataset first and then using transfer learning to create individual models for each timeseries?